# Nginx proxy pass even if file do not exists

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have this piece of code at my nginx configuartion

```
server {
    server_name example.org;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://198.25.34.19;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_bind $server_addr;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

This code above is working! But if the file does not exists, the redirect does not work.

How can I fix this? I want to redirect if the file does not exists on current server.

Thank you.

Comment: What redirect are you talking about? There is no redirect here.

Comment: My mistake, a proxy pass even is the file does not exists*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process 404 responses in the reverse proxy, you will need to intercept them. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://...;
    ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 =302 /some/other/page;
}
```

Comment: Hello, how can I process 404 responses to external server? The file does not exists on the current server, only on external server, I want acess xxx.com and request a file from yyy.com